# UITableView Footer Covers Bottom Cell on Scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

When I call scrollToRowAtIndexPath on my UITableView using the last row's index path, it scrolls to the bottom minus the height of my footer. So, it still needs to scroll down the "footer's height" distance to really be at the bottom.

I have set the footer's height using the "heightForFooterInSection" delegate function, and add the footer to the table using the "viewForFooterInSection" function.

Adding this line to viewDidLoad() caused the problem:

`tblComments.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

However, it is necessary so that the UITableView cells resize properly.

Hopefully I provided enough detail. Thank you.

Edit:

I have found a hack to sort of solve the issue. After I call scrollToRowAtIndexPath, I call it again after a 0.3 second delay. Of course, this is far from ideal, as I don't know if 0.3 seconds will always be enough. I'd still like to see if there is a solution rather than a hack.

Comment: Not sure if you need it to be based on section, but if you're having problems with resizing within the rows, can you just use the tableFooterView property? You can set the view there directly instead of overriding the `heightForFooterInSection` and `viewForFooterInSection` methods?

Comment: I know this doesn't solve your problem, but maybe you can circumvent it that way? Won't work if you have multiple sections though.

Comment: I only have one section. Thank you for the suggestion, I just edited the OP so you can see what I did to temporarily solve the issue. However, it is far from ideal.